# advanced asp.net improve performance

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql-server-2005, iis-6, windows-server-2003

asked for help on my application , that's run on windows server 2003 and iis 6.0 ,this applications gross now , users now about 60,000 per day. and that what i did to make it faster

a.SQL server 2005 :

- all query i convert it to storedprocedure.
- all tables have indexes on FK.
- most on select statement from view.
- never use * in all command.

but still have dead lock error

B. js file :

- include it all in one file
- optimize file

c. css file:

- optimized in one file

D.asp.net 2.0 :

- most of default page run on json object by calling web method and
  render page or usercontrols.
- all photo i saved on server max size to it 20KB.
- enable caching

E.windows server 2003:

- when i use performance tool in windows 80% of it come from sql

any suggest to improve performance of this application

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for this kind of question

Comment: For your views/selects, check that you only use LEFT JOIN when applicable, when dealing with two large tables and joining INNER JOIN is faster. It is a small win but when your that optimised small wins are all that remains

Comment: For me the SQL that eats 80% did not give any clue. You must tell us and you to focus on the real issue - what is your real problem here - Do you have many dead locks ? did your page come slow ? Did you database files are huge ? its a design problem, or its a huge traffic problem ?

Comment: its huge traffic problem i have around 60,000 user per day

Comment: @maksoud Can you tell me the site to look the speed of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a broad question.  There are lots of way you can do performance improvement following link has some best practice.

http://www.dotnetjalps.com/2009/05/increase-performance-in-aspnet.html

Try REDGATE ANTS profiler for profiling your application and see where the bottleneck is.
http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/

For memory leak use dottrace memory profiler and see how your application doing.
http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/

You can also check performance counter via process explorer on your server.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4(v=vs.100).aspx

For stored procedure you can measure time via direclty executing query string. If any stored procedure is taking more then a second then you should refactor that.

Here are few links that might be usefull for you.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196378/Best-Practices-to-Improve-ASP-NET-Web-Application

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23306/10-ASP-NET-Performance-and-Scalability-Secrets

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647787.aspx